# "Temporarily" set session timeout for method - setMaxInactiveInterval

Tags: java, session, web

In my web application a user can call a long running backend service (synchronous request). The execution time for this service should **not** count for the websession timeout so in my code i tried:

```
handleUserRequest() {
  HttpSession session = ...getSession(false);
  int oldMaxInactiveInterval = session.getMaxInactiveInterval();
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(BIG_VALUE);
  <LONG RUNNING TASK>
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(oldMaxInactiveInterval);
}
```

This is not working as expected. The temporary session timeout is not recognized for this "method call". The user session times out according to the oldMaxInactiveInterval value.

Is it possible to do, what I want to do? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your `oldMaxInactiveInterval` defaultsession-timeout is defined in web.xml for example 60. means it's 60 minutes. when you will set using `session#setMaxInactiveInterval()` It will be always in second(1 mimnute)

It sets the default session timeout for the web app

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout> // 60 minutes
</session-config>
```

Calling `session.setMaxInactiveInterval()` sets the timeout for the particular session it is called on, and overrides the default.

Remember this difference, too - the `deployment descriptor` version uses minutes, and `session.setMaxInactiveInterval()` uses seconds.

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300); // Its sets the 5 minutes
```

Comment: Yes,  I know. That's not the problem. ;-)

Comment: I think a new session timeout applies to all the *following* requests but not to the request where the new session timeout is set. :(

Comment: @Ginkgochris I don't know what's your exact scenario.But you should know this 3or seconds are more. If you have long process then you must need Asynchronous processing for it, Or use EJBTimer scheduler, Quartz, Servlet 3.0 support Asynchronous to notify user.